# apache virtual hosting configuration will return a site if used any sub domain

Tags: apache

I have done a virtual hosting on a domain and few sub domains

> example.com 
>   a1.example.com 
>   a2.example.com

When I attempt to access example.com or a1.example.com or a2.example.com. I get the corresponding site, but when I try to access xyss.example.com i get the example.com. Meaning, it will always return example.com with any sub domain i use even if the sub domain does not exists.

any idea's on how I could accomplish this?

regards,

Comment: what is your configuration look like? (httpd.conf and .htaccess)

Comment: This sounds exactly like how apache is supposed to behave if you request a domain [or subdomain] that does not exist, it's returning the default domain. I've read your question a couple of times nad don't quite understand what you are expecting to happen or want to happen. Please update & clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you manage several VirtualHosts in apache they're **sorted in alphabetic order of the file used to store the configurations**.

That's why in Debian the default Virtualhost is prefixed by a 000. In Debian, with 3 virtualhosts you would have 3 files included from /etc/apache2/sites-enabled, in this naming convention:

```
/etc/
 \-apache2/
  \-sites-enabled/
    \- 000-default
     - 001-bar.example.com
     - 150-foo.example.com
```

If you do (to list Virtualhosts)2:

```
. /etc/apache2/envvars #for debian only
apache2 -S
```

You'll get:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server _default (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:38)
         port 80 namevhost _default (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:38)
         port 80 namevhost bar.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-bar.example.com:13)
         port 80 namevhost foo.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/150-foo.example.com:13)
```

But that would also work with VirtualHosts configuration included from any other directory.

So you need to remove the 'default' default virtualhost and ensure your example.com Virtualhost is the first in that list (so the previous command will show you this VH 2 times, the first time to state it's the default one).